# Displaying raw file content as Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github, render

How could I display the raw file content as done in GitHub when displaying the file after clicking a "view raw" link?

E.g. I wanted to diplay `*.html` file's source but rails takes `html` in `params[:format]` and renders in its own way.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got this to work, though I am not exactly sure how you would want to use this in your application. Consider this a proof of concept that hopefully helps you achieve your goal.

Let's say you want to render the raw contents of the index action for your products controller if someone requests the "text" format:

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  @raw = render_to_string('products/index.html', :content_type => 'text/html')

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.text do
      render :text => @raw, :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end
  end
end
```

This obviously isn't ideal since you're stuffing the "raw" version of the view in a variable even if someone requests the normal html format, but putting it in the format.text block screws up the content type for the partials inside index.html.erb. Again, this is just a proof of concept I came up with.

At any rate, now when you hit:

```
/products.txt
```

You will get the raw HTML of the page. And if you hit:

```
/products
```

It will render the normal, interpreted HTML in the browser.